# Pressing any keyboard buttons removes hash url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a bug on a website I am maintaining. What happens is if you click **any** button on the keyboard, the hash url gets removed and the browser jumps to the top of the page. I thought this was an issue with my smooth scroll function but I removed it completely and nothing changed. I also tried to set default actions for arrow clicks but it still removed the hash url.

You can see it happening [here](https://iiwisdom.com/msft-2014/#board), and all you need to do is click any button on your keyboard to see the issue.

Is there anyway to prevent the browser from removing the hash url?

Comment: could post the code ?

Comment: I couldnt reproduce the issue. I'm on Chrome/Mac

Comment: @DinoMyte the code base is pretty large, and I can't find where the actual problem is arising. I am just trying to counter this problem by preventing the browser from removing the hash url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the Javascript file named `app.js` included within your website.

Somewhere, you check for keyboard input like this:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 37 || 39) { //left right arrow
    var activeMem = $('.detail-active').find(textCenter).text();
    var spaces = activeMem.toString().replace(/ /g, '-');
    var comma = spaces.replace(',', '').toLowerCase();
    var clean = comma.replace('.', '').toLowerCase();
    if (clean.substring(clean.length-1) == ".") {
      clean = clean.substring(0, clean.length-1);
    }
    var hash = '#'+clean;
    location.hash = hash;
  }
});
```

The problem is with this condition `if(e.keyCode == 37 || 39)`.
It should be `if(e.keyCode == 37 || e.keyCode == 39)`